# Eslint - Each Argument in a New Line Breaks The Indentation Rule?

Tags: javascript, format, indentation, eslint

Im not sure whether this is how its suppose to be. Here is the screenshot of Atom.

[image: atom editor]

My formating is if there are more than 2 parametres, then break them down into an argument per line. As per the image, `Eslint` expected indentation of 10 tabs. Is there a way, to make it accept the 3 tabs continuation without having to switch the formating off for the file or section?